# Localized Site -> howto redirect Browser

Tags: redirect, language

How would you **redirect users** with an "english browser" **automatically** to the english site? I have no idea if this can be made with craft or if this is an apache webserver thing. Any idea?

```
'domain.de' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'de' => 'http://domain.de/',
        'en' => 'http://domain.de/en/',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Hey Patte, you should probably find an answer to your question here: [Locale change based on geolocation](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/locale-change-based-on-geolocation).

Comment: Hey carls, meanwhile I have successfully tested this solution: 302 redirects to locales in main index.php 
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/302-redirects-to-locales-in-main-index-php

I have no chance to install an apache module so I hope this solves my client needs.

Comment: Hi Patte... If that solution works for you, feel free to add it as an official answer (it's ok to answer your own question), and even mark the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 5):

Here is what i have done. Not sure if it helps you. I can't add comments. So here you go. This is based on [geo](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-geo) plugin

Plugin serviceclass:

```
//to get local ele
private function getLocalElement()
    {
        $source=craft()->request->getRequestUri();
         if($source==''){
             $source = 'home';
         }
        return  craft()->elements->getElementByUri($source);
    }

//finds locale and redirect
private function redirectToLang()
   {
       $value=$this->detectBrowserLang()."_".strtolower($this->detectCountryCode());
       if(in_array($value, craft()->i18n->siteLocaleIds)==1){
            $element=$this->getLocalElement();
            if(!is_null($element)){
                $localElementUri = craft()->elements->getElementUriForLocale($element->id, $value);
                header('Location: '.$this->configBaseUrl().'/'.$value.'/'.$localElementUri, true, 302); 
            }            
        }      

   }

//browser lang
private function detectBrowserLang()
   {
        $browserLang=craft()->request->getBrowserLanguages();
        if(isset($browserLang)){
            $lang=substr(strtolower($browserLang[0]),0,2); 
            return $lang;
        }
   }

//detect country code by geo
private function detectCountryCode()
    {
        $info=$this->getInfoGeo();
        $countryCode=strtoupper($info["country_code"]);      
        return $countryCode;          
    }
```

Basically checking browser lang and country code(geo) with craft locales.

Answer (score 2):

I recently released Country Redirect, a plugin that handles this smoothly: https://superbig.co/plugins/country-redirect

It lets you map which countries get redirected to which locales, let visitors override the country, and easily let you create a locale nav based on the country mapping.